# Hook in a sidebar widget and add some markup

Tags: filters, hooks, sidebar

I'm looking to hook into a sidebar widget, this one in particular loads the members.

All I'm looking to do is add a link into the widget, I managed to get a result but it's not quite right. It doesn't load the original function, instead it replaces it.

Here's how I far I got:

```
function members_dir_link(){
echo '<a href="/members/">View Members</a>';
}
add_filter('bp_has_members','members_dir_link');
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? What widget are you using?
I don't think you should output anything in `bp_has_members` filter - it's called many times, not only in this widget.

Comment: Perhaps that's not the right function exactly, I'm trying to target the widget so I can insert static html without modifying the core code.

Comment: OK, but what widget exactly are you trying to modify? What is the name of this widget?

Comment: It's the members widget, it displays all the users avatars. I'm not really modifying as such, I'm adding html code tot he existing output of this widget.

Comment: It's a buddypress widget, in case you didn't know that already..

Comment: OK. I don't think it can be done. I'm sorry, but this widget has no hooks in there. You can only use `bp_has_members` hook, but you shouldn't use it to echo anything, because it's used in many other places, so you may break some things doing it this way.

Comment: Damn, how do I turn this widget into a theme widget? Is there a way to do that? Then I could modify it as much as I want to without changing the core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can be done. I'm sorry, but this widget has no hooks in there. You can only use `bp_has_members` hook, but you shouldn't use it to echo anything, because it's used in many other places, so you may break some things doing it this way.

The only way I can see to achieve this (and it's not perfect), is to write your own widget based on this BP widget. To do that you should:

1. Find the original widget's source code. (It's in `bp-core/bp-core-widgets.php` file)
2. Copy it's code and place it in your themes `function.php`
3. Rename it properly (take care of class name, and so on).
4. Register your new widget with:

   add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("");') );

You can also try to inherit this new widget class from original BP widget class (you won't need to copy entire source code then).